# Change value of variable in a if-statment argument depending of the if-statments outcome

Tags: javascript, if-statement, woocommerce, product

What I'm trying to do is to contact WooCommerce every fifth seconds to check if a product have been edited. I can do that by asking for res[0].date_modified. Then I compare the time it was created (`res[0].date_created`) and last modified.

If the values are the same the product have never been modified. However if the product get modified I no longer want to compare the time the product was created and last modifed.

I now want to compare the time with the last time it got modified with "`res[0].date_modified`" so I can see if it gets modified another time.

This is what I have come up with:

```
function lookForEdit(){

WooCommerce.get('products/',  function(err, WooData, res) {
    res=JSON.parse(res)

    var comp = res[0].date_created;

    if(comp == res[0].date_modified){
        console.log("the product haven't been modified")
    }
    else{
        console.log("The product have been edited")
        comp = res[0].date_modified;
    }
})
}

setInterval(lookForEdit, 5000);
```

I understand why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to fix it.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: How would the clientside know that information?

Comment: @epascarello: it polls the info. So it can store state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a global variable to store the last value would be enough, just check if it is defined first, if not take the `date_create` value.

Of course, you can check `date_modifed` only if it is not defined for a unmodifed item.

In that case, you just need to check if `date_modifed` value is defined, if it is, compare with `comp` (still global). Then if there are different store the new value.

PS: Sorry, I can't write a code since I didn't write javascript in a will. I end up in that question by mistake ^^

This would be a pseudocode of it

```
global comp;

function(){
   if(comp not defined)
        comp = date_created

    if(comp != date_modified)
        //changed
        comp = date_modified;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Well, right off the bat, you are setting `comp = res[0].date_created` and then, if they are equal you are setting `comp = res[0].date_modified` but then the very next time you call the api, you are overwriting `comp` with the date created again. You should be using 2 separate variables to track the information. You should use 2 separate more descriptive names for the values you are trying to monitor.

Comment: Yes I get that I over write the new value with the original time every time I call the function. But how can I replace a variable in with another one in a If-statment?

Comment: I guess i'm not following what you mean by "replace a variable in with another one in a if-statement." comp is locally scoped to the api call so it will automatically be destroyed once the api call is resolved. If you want to do something outside of the api call, then you should use a global variable to track the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code runs every 5 seconds, I suppose you could check that the last modification happened less than 5 seconds ago :

```
if(comp == res[0].date_modified){
    console.log("the product hasn't been modified")
}
else if (new Date(Date.now().getTime() - 5000) < res[0].date_modified) {
    console.log("the product hasn't been modified since the last check");
}
else{
    console.log("The product has been edited")
    comp = res[0].date_modified;
}
```